# Code style for output after a for loop

Tags: coding-style

I really like to combine a trivial output statement after a forloop onto one line such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
//
} putchar('\n');
```

Are there any code style guides that support this usage? If not, is it common?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't see what you'd gain from doing this. On the other hand, it does look more cluttered.

If you don't want the `put char('\n')` to stick out in a separate line, extract the for loop with the `put char('\n')` into a separate function.